# Dockerising a go rest api

Tags: docker

I have made a go rest api that connects to a PG database. it works completely fine. I now need to dockerize it, and to say i know nothing about Docker is an understatement. Ive tried following a few tutorials online but i cant get it to work. This is literally the first time ive ever touched Docker, but i see a printout from my code when I call docker-compose up. I just cant seem to connect to any of the apis. I am listening in my Go project to localhost:8080. Im clearly doing something, probably basic or fundamentally wrong but i dont know where to check or what to properly ask really. Anyone know what might be my issue?

Dockerfile:

```
# Start from golang base image
FROM golang:alpine as builder

# ENV GO111MODULE=on

# Add Maintainer info
LABEL maintainer="Me"

# Install git.
# Git is required for fetching the dependencies.
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache git

# Set the current working directory inside the container 
WORKDIR /app

# Copy go mod and sum files 
COPY go.mod go.sum ./

# Download all dependencies. Dependencies will be cached if the go.mod and the go.sum files are not changed 
RUN go mod download 

# Copy the source from the current directory to the working Directory inside the container 
COPY . .

# Build the Go app
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o main .

# Start a new stage from scratch
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates

WORKDIR /root/

# Copy the Pre-built binary file from the previous stage. Observe we also copied the .env file
COPY --from=builder /app/main .
COPY --from=builder /app/.env .       

# Expose port 8080 to the outside world
EXPOSE 8080

#Command to run the executable
CMD ["./main"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: full_app
    build: .
    ports: 
      - 8080:8080 
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - api:/usr/src/app/
    depends_on:
      - fullstack-postgres          
    networks:
      - fullstack


  fullstack-postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: full_db_postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}  
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
      - DATABASE_HOST=${DB_HOST} 
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - database_postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - fullstack

volumes:
  api:
  database_postgres:                  

# Networks to be created to facilitate communication between containers
networks:
  fullstack:
    driver: bridge
```

my .env:

```
# Postgres Live
DB_HOST=fullstack-postgres                      
# DB_HOST=127.0.0.1                             # when running the app without docker 
DB_DRIVER=postgres
API_SECRET=98hbun98h                            # Used for creating a JWT. Can be anything 
DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=password
DB_NAME=postgres
DB_PORT=5432
```

This is the printout after i call docker-compose up, the first line is the printout from my code:

```
full_app              | server running
full_db_postgres      |
full_db_postgres      | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
full_db_postgres      |
full_db_postgres      | 2022-04-10 19:54:56.812 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.2 (Debian 14.2-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
full_db_postgres      | 2022-04-10 19:54:56.813 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
full_db_postgres      | 2022-04-10 19:54:56.813 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
full_db_postgres      | 2022-04-10 19:54:56.837 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
full_db_postgres      | 2022-04-10 19:54:56.859 UTC [27] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-04-10 19:53:01 UTC
full_db_postgres      | 2022-04-10 19:54:56.874 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
pgadmin_container     | NOTE: Configuring authentication for SERVER mode.
pgadmin_container     |
pgadmin_container     | [2022-04-10 19:55:49 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
pgadmin_container     | [2022-04-10 19:55:49 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://[::]:80 (1)
pgadmin_container     | [2022-04-10 19:55:49 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
pgadmin_container     | [2022-04-10 19:55:49 +0000] [90] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 90
```

Comment: One thing that sometimes trip people up is that their application binds to localhost, i.e. it only accepts connections from the same machine as the application is running on. In a Docker context, each container has it's own IP address, so now the connections look like they're coming from another machine and it stops working. Make sure that your Go program binds to 0.0.0.0.

Comment: so: http.ListenAndServe("0.0.0.0:8080", router) ?

Comment: That looks right, yes.

Comment: Still getting the same. In Postman I am using: localhost:8080/room/test. /room/test is one of my apis but it says: "Could not get response"

Comment: never mind. I never saved the file in my IDE before building. @HansKilian if you were here I would buy you several drinks in gratitude.

Comment: No worries. The files you posted looked correct, so it was a qualified guess. Sometimes you get lucky with guesses :) Glad you got it to work.